# iOS Today Widget - Determine if active

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

1. Can the container app determine if embedded today widget is active or not ?
   (active = the user add the widget in notification center)
2. There is a way to force activate the embedded today widget ? When user first install the app or update it, can the embedded today widget be active by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: yes you can using AppGroups. Using that you can pass data between the extension and the container app. In your case that would be isInstalled=YES. 
A different problem checking if it's removed.

Simple as NSUserDefaults. Plus you need to setup your project capabilities for that.

2: no